# Protractor browser select from multiCapabilities

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor for my e2e tests. i have multiple browsers set up in the `protractor.conf.js` file and they all execute as needed. Screenshot is attached.

Objective: I wish to set up my package.json scripts so that i can choose just one of them and have only that one run, without going in to comment it out...

**`protractor.conf.json`**

[image]

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I've done a little more digging into this and i know it is possible to override a spec you wish to test by putting it into a suite and then running --suite=suiteA. To clarify, i wish to do the same thing and override which browser instance i wish to run such as (--browser.name=desktop) or such.

Comment: or in this case --multiCapabilities.name=desktop

Comment: Using multi-capibilities protractor-config.js, I have tried to specify the browser on command line with `--browser chrome`, but protractor warns that it will ignore capabilities, if multi-capabilities are defined and the command line option is ignored. I have found a [feature request on Github angular/protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4923). However, it is still open as of today.